# Haskell: Value Function

Tags: haskell

I'm still doing the exercise from the book and the one exercise says that I should create a function: `value :: Hand -> Int`, which returns the value of the hand.

My code so far looks like this:

```
data Hand = PairOf Rank | ThreeOf1 Rank | ThreeOf2 Suit
           
value: Hand -> Int
otherwise = 0
--
```

I now have another problem, because I don't know how to describe "Nothing".
Nothing is described here as a possible hand combination in which Pair, ThreeOf1 and ThreeOf2 do not occur.
Would otherwise = 0 work or doesn't that make much sense?

Thanks again for the suggestions, I corrected them! Thanks also in advance for explanations and help.

Comment: "or their ranks are equal and suits decide" This is not what your function actually does. "2 cards of the same rank" Then why are you including the rank *twice*? You may want to include the rank *and two suits* if you want a value of `Hand` to represent a unique hand. Same thing about all the other cases. "I don't know exactly how to create the value function" Use pattern matching. Any Haskell tutorial or textbook should explain it on one of the first pages.

Comment: It is probably a bad idea to use `Nothing` as one of your constructors, as `Nothing` is already used by the Haskell library as a `Maybe` constructor.

Comment: You could have pattern matching clauses in your `value` function, such as:  `value (Flush s0 s1 s2) = 3`

Comment: “...or their ranks are equal and suits decide.” - But Haskell uses lexicographic order by default, so this is exactly what you would get by just using `deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)`

Comment: Some of your `Hand` constructors are too general. `PairOf Seven Seven` makes sense, sure, but what about `PairOf Seven Eight`. `PairOf` itself already *implies* two cards of equal rank; you only need to specify *which* rank that is. `PairOf Rank` is sufficient. The same reasoning applies to `ThreeOf` and `Flush` as well (a flush is already all cards of one suit; just name that suit that all the cards share, not the identical suit of each card separately).

Comment: thank you everyone! I understood it and it works now, but how can I do this with Nothing? could you give me a hint and explain it?

Comment: Where you given the instruction to use a `Hand` data type like this? To my mind the more complex (and interesting) bit is looking a a group of cards and calculating whether you have a pair, or a triple, or a flush, etc. Your `value` function is starting from a type that effectively already contains the information about what value is there (which is why you're able to ignore all the actual contents of the `Hand` constructors; the value is already determined by which constructor was there). But that wouldn't yet let you determine the value of an arbitrary set of 5 cards.

Comment: i.e. I would have expected `value :: Hand -> Int` would go along with something like `type Hand = [Card]`, not `data Hand = PairOf ... | ...`. But maybe they're working you up to another function that will go from `[Card]` to `Hand` later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`otherwise` won't work here. What you want is an irrefutable pattern that will match anything, and further since you don't care what gets matched, you specifically want the pattern `_`:

```
value :: Hand -> Int
value (PairOf r1) = 1
value (ThreeOf r1) = 2
value (Flush s1) = 3
value _ = 0
```

Since you don't care about what *kind* of pair, etc you get, you can also use `_` in the other cases:

```
value :: Hand -> Int
value (PairOf _) = 1
value (ThreeOf _) = 2
value (Flush _) = 3
value _ = 0
```

If you wanted to match `Nothing` (or whatever name you come up with that doesn't conflict with the `Maybe` constructor) specifically, it's just

```
value Nothing = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems you might be having is that there is no Nothing.

Here's the full type of Hands for holdem:

```
data HandRank
  = HighCard Rank Rank Rank Rank Rank
  | OnePair Rank Rank Rank Rank
  | TwoPair Rank Rank Rank
  | ThreeOfAKind Rank Rank Rank
  | Straight Rank
  | Flush Rank Rank Rank Rank Rank
  | FullHouse Rank Rank
  | FourOfAKind Rank Rank
  | StraightFlush Rank
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Generic)
```

The extra ranks in the data type are there to distinguish hands, so a pair of aces with a King & Queen kicker beats a pair of aces with a King & Jack kicker. But otherwise, it's the same as your setup.

Once you have a complete transformation from a set of cards to a hand value, there is no nothing. What you might be thinking of as nothing is the HighHand line in the sum type. If your context is that's it for possible hands, then I would add a NoValue to the Hand sum type, as better than outputting a `Maybe Hand`.

Using the wild cards `otherwise _` or `value _` introduces a chance of a bug because you might forget about coding up a full house, say, and your existing function would work. If you forget to code one of the sum types, and you don't have a match-any pattern, the compiler will complain. Providing the compiler with all branches of a sum type is also a hot development area of GHC, and it will be fast.